# Plotting lines from different rows of a 2 column text file

Tags: python, file, plot, rows, lines

I have a text file that is 600 rows by 2 columns, the columns are tab delimited.

0.029 | 0.001
0.056 | 0.004
0.083 | 0.007
0.111 | 0.009
0.138 | 0.012
and 595 more...

I have code that opens this file and plots all of the x values against y

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x, y = np.loadtxt('BC108.txt', delimiter='\t', unpack=True)
plt.plot(x,y,)
```

[Resultant plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLkir.png)

However, the 600 rows are actually 6 different data sets of 100 points. My code plots every single point and connects them, how can I individually access and plot each of the 100 rows as six different lines on the same graph?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`np.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html). You can specify `skip_header` to skip x rows and `max_rows` to limit the rows read to 100.

Eg.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for i in range(6):
    # Every iteration start 100 rows later
    x,y = np.genfromtxt('BC108.txt', delimiter='\t', skip_header=(i*100) unpack=True, max_rows=100)
    plt.plot(x,y,)
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Oddly the `max_rows` is unrecognized as an argument, but I'll have a look.

Comment: Looks like it's new in numpy 1.10.0, so if you haven't updated in a while that'd be why!